# how to re-level and support small section of floor

Tags: repair, subfloor, water-damage

In upstairs bathroom, the caulk between tub and tile was leaking, which lead to water damage in the subfloor and then a section of the tile floor to sag (see picture). There is an access hole directly below the tub, and from that limited viewport, it looks like the wood damage is localized to directly under the sagging tile.

My first thought for fixing the sagging floor section was to cut out the drywall below, install new  floor plywood between the joists, securing it by new blocking screwed into the floor joists.

Are there other approaches for fixing this, like say drilling a few small holes in the 1st floor drywall and filling the sub-floor with expanding foam?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Expanding foam will not provide any structural support at all.

Comment: There are no shortcuts, and that leaves your question as too broad. You need major repairs. Good luck.

Comment: Spilling tons and tons water with or without the offensive caulk will cause water damage. The caulking failure may have been an early warning sign for all of that damage. Your plywood from below idea sounds plausible, except the new plywood means the saturating water can't evaporate very well from below. By the time it evaporates you could have substantial mold. Is the shower door new? Have you fixed the water source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to ever step on this location.  the piece that is more worrying is how affected are the joists that are carrying the load from the tub and water.  if those fail your tub ends up downstairs.

if the joists below are in good shape and you just want a cosmetic repair here I'd probably just get a porcelin tile or 2cm white quartz countertop material and make a tile ledge that fits into the nook and end where the vanity kick ends.  You'd want the substrate to be stable though so while you have below open add some dimensional re-inforcement.

Your wall is also missing some finishing details so another piece that is installed vertically and ends at the deck of the tub could finish the area off to a relatively nice look without ripping everything out.